# React-Hook-Form Input Element is Empty in Inspect Element but Not in Browser

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I am using `react-form-hook` in a project. I have css styles based on input field value attributes. `react-form-hook` is setting the values of all the inputs but doesn't show in `inspect element` niegther my css styles work. I just want to know how react-form-hook set the values on input elements when there is no actual value. Here is the code

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';

const CustomInput = (props: any) => {
  const { label, name, className, type, onChange, register, setValue, value, disabled } = props;
  return (
    <div className="custom--input--container">
      <input
        type={type}
        name={name}
        ref={register}
        className={`custom--input ${className}`}
        onChange={e => {
          onChange();
          setValue(name, e.target.value, { shouldValidate: true });
        }}
      />
      <span className="custom--input--label">{label}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomInput;
```

Component used here

```
  <CustomInput
            label="First Name*"
            type="text"
            name={SettingsFormFields.FIRST_NAME}
            className={classNames({
              error: errors[SettingsFormFields.FIRST_NAME],
            })}
            setValue={setValue}
            register={register}
            onChange={enableButton}
          />
```

value is being displaed

[image]

No value in inspect element

[image]